# SQL table references

Tags: sql

First, I am sorry about the bad title, but after 5 minutes I couldn't come up with anything better.

Assume the following please: There are people and bank accounts and I wish to implement two tables to simulate that. A person has an ID (primary key) and a name. A bank account also has an ID (primary key), an owner (foreign key) and a value.
Here is my code:

```
create table Person(
  ID integer primary key,
  name varchar(200) not null
);

create table Account(
  ID integer primary key,
  owner integer references Person(ID),
  value number not null
);
```

Now, is there a way for a Person to "know" which accounts are associated to it without `select * from Account where owner = XY`?
I asked my teacher, but didn't get an answer even related to SQL. On the internet, I couldn't find any advice, so I asked here.
Please forgive me this question, but I'm so used to object-oriented languages, in which the class Person would contain an Enumerable to store all accounts.

Comment: Another way to look at this (and a possibly more flexible design) would be to have Three tables, Person, Account, PersonAccounts.  Think of person and account as objects either of which could be a collection under eachother. Person.Accounts(i) or Account.Person(i)  This is because multiple people could be on the same account or a person may have more than one account.  Owner in your account table would be in the associative table personAccounts; then to know what accounts a person has you'd look no further than the PersonAccounts table.

Comment: that would be a "n-to-n" relation, but I wanted a "1-to-1" relation as showed above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the way **relational** databases work, they have tables with **relations**.

Because it's relational you can query for a `Person` and get all `Account`s related to that person in one query. To do this you need to perform a `JOIN`.

#### code example

```
SELECT * FROM Person
JOIN Account ON (Person.ID = Account.owner)
WHERE Person.ID = XY;
```

If you want a **document oriented** database you can use something like MongoDB, where you can embed an `Account` directly into a `Person` document.

Comment: Which means, in my current design (or relational design in general), a Person doesn't even know that Accounts exist at all

Comment: Correct.  A person has a relationship with an account; but this isn't a 1-1 relationship either.  for it truly to be 1-1 you would need to track the account in the person table; but maintaining such a relationship would be problematic from a coding standpoint.  An account and a person would have to first be created then each record would have to be updated with the others key. You wouldn't be able to.  To enforce integrity,  you could make the combination unique, but not a primary key.